# C# How to display an integer entered by the user as time

Tags: c#, integer, timespan

I'm writing a program where you need to enter in minutes how long you have been cycling and then it displays how long you have been riding in hours `hh:mm`
so for instance if the user wrote in 88 mins it should display 1:28

I have looked for hours now and cannot find how to do it, probably doesn't help I am a total novice to coding :)

```
 //input data
            Console.Write("Number of Minutes spent Cycling...");
            int cycling = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
//perform calculations

            TimeSpan cTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(cycling);
            string fromTimeString = cTime.ToString("hh':'mm");
//output results
            Console.WriteLine("cycling {0}", cTime);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

this is just one of the many ways i have tried, thank you for any help :)

Comment: Don't you mean to write "FromMinutes"?

Comment: thank you i just saw this my self, such a stupid mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some minor tweak necessary:

```
//input data
        Console.Write("Number of Minutes spent Cycling...");
        int cycling = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
//perform calculations

        TimeSpan cTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(cycling);
        string fromTimeString = cTime.ToString("h\\:mm");
//output results
        Console.WriteLine("cycling {0}", fromTimeString);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

So basically changing `fromHours` to `fromMinutes` for fitting your input and fixing your format-string according to this documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx
And I changed `hh:mm` to `h:mm` since you probably don't want to have leading zeros for the hours.

And of course the small syntax flaw with the printout that you did use `cTime` instead of your prepared string.

Comment: thank you for answer, i didnt notice the syntax error thanks again :)

Comment: also i tried having ("h:mm") and i got a crash error i then changed it to (h':'mm) and it works :)

Comment: My bad... for the `:` you need an escape character... so it should be `"h\\:mm"`

Comment: And your solution is correct too of course. I just personally don't really like this syntax with string-delimiters. :D

Answer (score 1):

You are prompting user to enter time in minutes and after that you are trying to parse is as hours. You should use TimeSpan.FromMinutes(cycling).

Comment: do you know if i can remove the seconds part ?